# jms message interceptor

Tags: jms, interceptor

Is there anyway to intercept messages going to/from a java app and an activeMQ queue?

Any opensource utilities I can avail of?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aspect-oriented programming.

But it does beg the question: why would you want to do this?  Logging, monitoring, alerting?  Those are all cross-cutting concerns that AOP can address.

Comment: thats a good suggestion. Im really looking for a quick once off tool I can use for a proof of concept. Im in a situation where messages are being taken off the queue, but im not getting the expected output in my code. I have used the tcp/ip filter ine eclipse previously for viewing soap requests and responses and found it extremely useful

Comment: I'd use something like a packet sniffer or Fiddler to do it.

Comment: AOP has been deprecated.

Comment: By whom? Can still do it in Spring.