# Can Fiddler intercept JMS messages?

Tags: jms, mule, wildfly, fiddler

I need to connect a Mule flow via JMS to Wildfly9. There is very little information available on how to do this (or whether it's even possible), so naturally I'm having [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33240127/367605). I want to try investigating the communicaton between Mule ESB and Wildfly, and I wonder if something like Fiddler can help me.

A similar question popped up five years ago, and @duffymo [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114187/jms-message-interceptor#comment4430826_4114222) that he'd "use something like a packet sniffer or Fiddler to do it." The problem is -- how? I've no experience with Fiddler, and am rather new to messaging, so I don't even know which protocols to filter on. I *do* know the IP (localhost), port, and queue name involved.

If I just start a newly installed Fiddler and send a few test messages, the "input window" keeps saying "No sessions captured".

Can I assume JMS goes over HTTP? How should I configure Fiddler?

Comment: JMS can go over HTTP but that's not always the case, more often not.  Fiddler can be seen as a proxy that sits between your requests and the server.  That's how it's capturing the data going over the wire.

Comment: What exactly protocol you are using? HornetQ can use amqp (binary), stomp (text), and rest (text) https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/interoperability.html Check wildfly settings in `acceptors` section, you can find port number too. I don't know how to configure fiddler for act like proxy, but you can use wireshark or tcpdump on given port.

Comment: Honestly - I don't know. Yes, HornetQ is definitely evident in the logs, but beyond that ... how can I tell?

Comment: The Mule tag seems unrelated to this question, which is about JMS and Fiddler.